# Deserialize a json in C# with Json.Net (NewtonSoft)

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json (v6.0.0.0) and I'm trying to deserialize a JSON into an enumeration.

I tried to use the attribute `EnumMember`, wich works for the serialization (send a JSON from a .Net Web API) but does not seem to work for the deserialization.

For begining, I have a model like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class MyModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the username
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"UserName")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userName", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

          /* .
             . REST OF THE MODEL
             .
             . */

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the enum model.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"EnumModel")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enummodel", Required = Required.Always)]
    public MyEnumModel EnumModel { get; set; }
}
```

MyEnumModel is an enum with those values:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnumModel
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "My Value 1")]
    MyValueOne,

    [EnumMember(Value = "My Value 2")]
    MyValueTwo,

    [EnumMember(Value = "My Value 3")]
    MyValueThree
}
```

When I serialize this enum, I get the correct value, defined by the attribute `EnumMember`. So in the result of the call, I have a JSON with value "My Value 1" or "My Value 2" or "My Value 3".

But when I send back the JSON with the same value ("My Value 1" for example), I have this error message:

```
"The value 'My Value 1' is not valid for EnumModel."
```

It seems to not use the `EnumMember` attribute for the deserialization because when I send the value "MyValueOne", it works.

What did I miss? How the attribute `[EnumMember()]` really works when I deserialize?

Thanks a lot for the help!

### EDIT: JSON sample

```
{  
   "userName":"testuser@gmail.com",
   "enummodel":"My Value 1"
}
```

### EDIT 2: Model validation

Sorry, but I forgot to mention one important thing. I'm using, in my controller a ModelState validation:

```
if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
}
```

I think the json is correctly deserialize with attributes EnumMember but the validation failed because the validator do not use the EnumMember to validate my model? Is it correct?

Comment: Do you have a sample JSON that's giving this error when you deserialize?

Comment: its working fine, i dont have any issues deserializing the json in winrt.

Comment: Thanks for the sample but I couldn't reproduce either. It worked just fine.

Comment: Try to add DataContract attribute to the enum. It says "To use EnumMemberAttribute, create an enumeration and apply the DataContractAttribute attribute to the enumeration" in the MSDN documentation

Comment: I already tried with the attribute [DataContract] to the enum, It did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is in the ModelState validation and not the deserialization.
With the `EnumMember` attribute, everything works fine.

Apparently the ModelState validation does not seem to read `EnumMember` attributes while validating. But this is an other subject :).

Thanks for the help.